# how to group by and push top n elements into an Array in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

this is my table structure:

[image: table schema]

How can I group by bq_category and show top 3 Brands (according to their prod count) nested in 1 array?

e.g.

```
 1111140     Cai, SKAGEN, ESPRIT 
 1111141     FIRRETTI 
 1111142     SOCOSI, Engelsurfer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ARRAY_AGG` function:

```
SELECT
  bq_category,
  ARRAY_AGG(prodBrand ORDER BY product_count DESC LIMIT 3) AS top_brands
FROM dataset.table
GROUP BY
  bq_category
```

Comment: if I wanted to get also the product_count as Map Object would it be correct to do:
SELECT          bq_category,     
STRUCT (ARRAY_AGG(prodBrand ORDER BY product_count DESC LIMIT 10) AS top_brands,   
          ARRAY_AGG(product_count ORDER BY product_count DESC LIMIT 10) AS product_count ) as blabla . 
        FROM dataset.table . 
GROUP BY  bq_category

Comment: You'd probably want to use `ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(prodBrand, product_count) ORDER BY product_count DESC LIMIT 10)`, actually.